# Microsoft Azure backup VM database every hour

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to have some help regarding this.. What I want to achieve is for my PostgreSQL installed on my docker-container in a VM to be backed-up every hour and that backup will be deleted for 2 hours.

Comment: What do you mean, delete backup point automatically?

Comment: Yes, Let's say I have a database named 'sample', it will be backed-up every hour and that certain created backed-up will be deleted after 2 hours so the backup will not be too many..

Comment: Do you mean Azure Backup? If yes, based on my knowledge, Azure does not support delete backup point automatically. You could set backup policy and determine  retention of daily backup point. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms#defining-a-backup-policy)

Comment: he asks for an hourly backup, azure backup doesn't support that

Comment: Yes, Azure backup supports backup daily and weekly.

Comment: I read about the microsoft blobs, and I think that's what I'm looking for but the question for now is.. How to transfer the backup of Postgresql database to the microsoft blob.. Is there a shell command for that?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada You had better update you question clearly.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT, it's pretty clear if you ask me, It simply means I want to back-up my database for every hour

Comment: Isn't it a variant to use some backup solution and, say, backup PostgreSQL on file-level every hour to MS Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read about the microsoft blobs, and I think that's what I'm looking for but the question for now is.. How to transfer the backup of Postgresql database to the microsoft blob.. Is there a shell command for that?

I find this [PostgreSQL-Backup tool](http://postgresql-backup.com/postgresql-blog/postgresql-backup/) provides a way to backup PostgreSQL, and it seems support [backup PostgreSQL to Azure Storage](http://postgresql-backup.com/postgresql-blog/how-to-backup-postgresql-to-azure-storage/), but this feature is **not free**.

Besides, even if you backup PostgreSQL to Azure Blob, currently Azure Blob storage does not provide auto-delete feature. You could try to [mount the file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share) and use the basic feature (not be charged) that PostgreSQL-Backup tool provides to backup PostgreSQL to that file share, and then you could run a [WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to detect backup files and dynamically&programmatically delete backup files.

Comment: Thankyou very much! What I did as for now is use S3.. It has the auto-delete feature that I need